# iPad battery calibration?

Tags: ipad, battery

I bought an old iPad 4 mini which was somewhere in desk with empty battery for last who-know-how-many years. The result is battery in a bad shape obviously, iPad works great but shuts down when battery shows about 45% left. No big deal, I can live with that, considering how difficult it is to replace. But, I'd expect it to recalibrate after some time, that iPadOS will notice and change its 0%-100% range to match lower capacity of the old battery but that didn't happen. After months of usage, it still behaves the same way. Is there any way how to force the recalibration?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11353/iphone-ipad-battery-charging-discharging-cycle?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to mention that this is what I always do. I always run the iPad until it switches of (at those 45%).

Comment: OK now, but what I SHOULD do then?

Comment: Multiple sources claim an "hard restart" by holding power button and home button till one sees Apple logo. You should keep power plugged it for the same, or at least keep it on higher %. https://www.wikihow.com/Hard-Reset-an-iPhone. I don't know anything more. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14990/ipad-2-battery-is-not-draining-completely?rq=1

Comment: That's incredible! Simple hard reset totally fixed the issue, battery percentage now works as expected, for the first time in months since initial charge. I used to thought about iPad/iPhone hard-reset along PC lines, like a solution for rare hang-ups but it clearly does more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As resolved in comments:

- Try calibrating the battery by fully charging to 100%, and then draining it to when it crashes. From personal experience, letting it die out slowly overnight is better than sudden crashes due to increased demand while using.  Some users report doing the charge-discharge cycle twice. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15568/313842
- If battery is still out of order, do a hard reset. This is an advice on several blogs I saw, and now this answer is one of them.

  > Press and hold the restart button combination. If the iPhone can't be shut down normally, simultaneously press and hold the right button combination for your iPhone:
  >
  > - iPhone 6S and earlier, iPad, and iPod Touch: Power button + home button
  > - iPhone 7 and 7 Plus: Power button + volume-down button
  > - iPhone 8, 8+, and X: Volume up, then volume down, then power button
  >
  > ... Continue holding the buttons. Do so for 10 seconds until you see the startup Apple logo on your screen, then release the buttons.

  https://www.wikihow.com/Hard-Reset-an-iPhone

  Adding some advice: keep iPhone plugged in, or at least on higher charge levels. Same reason for which Apple advices the same while upgrading iOS